# How to start inbuilt voice recorder application?

Tags: android

I have to attach voice recorded file as attachment to my android application. I have created a separate activity for voice recording without using inbuilt voice recorder application and it's working fine.

I thought of using the inbuilt application 'Voice Recorder' instead of using the activity which I have created.

I know that using Intent we should start the new activity. But I'm not able to find out how to start inbuilt voice recorder application and how it should be opened from my application?

Kindly let me know if anyone has experience in handling this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
public static final int ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND = 0;
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION); 
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. But in startActivityForResult(), I have given the request code as '0'. Kindly edit this so there may not be any confusion for android beginners.

Comment: ok nice .. If you think it was helpful you can accept/upvote my answer

Comment: sure. The audio which was saved is in MPEG format. How to convert it to .mp3 format while recording?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can put extra data for format. As far I knew it was not possible to record in direct mp3 format. you can use your own recorder. Better explore first whether the native recroder support mp3